# import packages from project directory

Tags: python, pipenv, python-packaging

I have the below file structure:

```
Project
    app.py
    package_A
        __init__.py
        a_module.py
    package_B
        __init__.py
        b_module.py
    package_C
        __init__.py
        c_module.py
    packageD
        __init__.py
        d_module.py
```

within `d_module.py` I am running the following import command:

`from package_C.c_module import someFunc`

I am continually getting a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_C'`. I have tried a number of different things from using a pipenv shell within the project directory, adding a `Pipfile` to the project directory. Also creating a virtual environment.

Right now the app.py file is empty as I am just starting the project, is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

For IDE like pycharm will automatically add parents directory to path, thus when ran manually it won't find packages as it's not listed in parents directory.

See this example:

```py
# file: B.__init__.py

try:
    from A import a
    print("IDE import")
except ImportError:
    from os import getcwd
    from sys import path

    path.append(getcwd() + "/..")
    from A import a
    print("without IDE")

print(a)
```

Folder structure:
[image: color is always beautiful]

Output - in IDE:

```
IDE import
<module 'A.a' from 'Z:\\github\\StackOverFlow\\A\\a.py'>
```

Output in terminal:

```
without IDE
<module 'A.a' from 'Z:\\github\\StackOverFlow\\B/..\\A\\a.py'>
```

And this also changes when directory is nested once more in project directory, in that case it will always import with path insertion used in `except` block.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the `__init__.py` in the `package_C` folder is blank?

Just putting an `__init__.py` in the a package folder does not automatically give you access to all modules within the package. You only get access to the modules that are imported in the `__init__.py` file.

This is because when you import a package python runs all the modules in the `__init__.py` file and adds them to the symbol table.

If you add `import c_module` in the `__init__.py` file, you should be able to import any objects from `c_module`.